# Sorting of merged arrays in YII

Tags: arrays, sorting, yii

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $sales = Sale::model()->findAll();
    $news = News::model()->findAll();

    $merged = CMap::mergeArray($sales, $news);

    $this->render('index', array(
        'merged ' => $merged
    ));
}
```

How can i sort $merged by any field (for example created field)?

Comment: It's very bad to do such things. Why you want to do this? Can't you just join tables? Why are you using AR for this, merging array of objects.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How can i join tables?

Answer (score 0):

Think better use join. But you can use this way(I don't know your conditions):

```
$union = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('created')
        ->from(Sale::model()->tableName())
        ->order('created ASC')
        ->getText();

$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('created')
        ->from(News::model()->tableName())
        ->union($union)
        ->order('created ASC');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($command->queryAll());
echo '</pre>';
die();
//or
$dataReader = $command->query();
foreach($dataReader as $row) { ... }
```

[UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

[JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)